# I am unable to test the below mentioned method in JUnit testcase and getting ClassCastException

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

For below method i am writing JUnit testcase for sonarqube coverage.

```
    @Transformer
    public Object errorUnWrapper(Message<?> message) {
        String value = "";
        try {
            if (!errorFlag) {               
                value = errorTransform(ESBConstants.SYSTEMERRCODE, ESBConstants.SYSTEMERROR, ESBConstants.SYSTEMTEXT);
                
            } else {                
                value = getbankholiday.getErrorMessage();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getbankholiday.getE2EObject().logMessage("3005", "Error Occurred in error unwrapper");          
            value = ESBConstants.SYSTEMERRORXML;            
        }
        MessageHeaders headers = ((MessagingException) message.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders();
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                .copyHeadersIfAbsent(headers).setHeader(ESBConstants.CONTENTTYPE, ESBConstants.CONTENTVALUE)
                .build();
    }
```

JUnit testcase:

```
@Test
    void testErrorUnWrapper() throws IOException {
        String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/test/resources/JunitTestCases/input/TC02_wltRequest.xml"),
                "UTF-8");
        test = MessageBuilder.withPayload(xml).build();
        errorTransform.errorUnWrapper(test);
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
```

but, unable to mock or test the below line in JUnit testcase.

`MessageHeaders headers = ((MessagingException) message.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders();`

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException
    at com.bt.or.esb.exceptions.ErrorTransform.errorUnWrapper(ErrorTransform.java:75)
    at com.bt.or.esb.exceptions.ErrorTransformTest.testErrorUnWrapper(ErrorTransformTest.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your productive code

```
(MessagingException) message.getPayload()
```

means you expect message.payload to be a MessagingException. But in your test, you create

```
MessageBuilder.withPayload(xml).build()
```

so payload will be a string. You need to build a message with a MessagingException as payload.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you need to refactor.
except for `value` everything else is common in `if` `else` and `catch` blocks

why don't you compute value first and then execute below two lines?

```java
MessageHeaders headers = ((MessagingException) message.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders();
return MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).copyHeadersIfAbsent(headers)
                    .setHeader(ESBConstants.CONTENTTYPE, ESBConstants.CONTENTVALUE).build();
```

Comment: Hi Rajani! now I have modified the code and getting ClassCastException. can you please help me?